# Form won't reset when dropdown clicked AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying go get two drop downs to reset when another dropdown is clicked but looks like the vm.reset() function is not being called; how can I call function even time a dropdown is changed?

```
<form name="Form1" ng-submit="vm.doSomething()">
    <div layout="row" style="padding-left:30px">
            <select name="Type" ng-model="vm.Type" ng-dropdown type="change" ng-change="vm.reset(Form1)">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose</option>
                <option ng-option value="1">1</option>
                <option ng-option value="2">2</option>
                <option ng-option value="3">3</option> 
                <option ng-option value="4">4</option> 
            </select>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="subType" style="padding-left:30px" ng-if="vm.Type == '1'">
        <label class="col-xs-6 control-label">Sub Type:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <select name="subType" ng-model="vm.subType" ng-dropdown required="true">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose</option>
                <option ng-option value="sub1">sub1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="subType" style="padding-left:30px" ng-if="vm.Type == '2'">
        <label class="col-xs-6 control-label">Sub Type:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <select name="subType" ng-model="vm.subType" ng-dropdown required="true">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose</option>
                <option ng-option value="sub2">sub2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
$scope.reset = function(form) {
    vm.ResetThisDropDown1 = undefined;
    vm.ResetThisDropDown2 = undefined;
}
```

Comment: Would you please post the Angular controller?

Comment: `ng-dropdown` is not a core AngularJS directive. Please include a link to the library or code of that directive.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be… **Complete** – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).